# Stack-allocated array of fixed-size strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to build an array of constant, fixed size strings. I could use malloc if I had to, but I am still learning C and I want to understand why my static approach below is not valid:

```
typedef char Str[4];

const Str a = "abc";
const Str b = "def";

const Str data[2] = {a, b};
```

GCC gives me

````
warning: initialization of ‘char’ from ‘const char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   10 | const Str data[2] = {a, b};
      |                      ^```
````

and

```
error: initializer element is not computable at load time
```

Why is the compiler saying that the first element of the array is `char` instead of `const Str` alias `constant char[4]`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**: I found out that using `const char *data[2] = {...}` works. I guess it has to do with the several constraints that come with arrays, which I am still grappling with and that can most times be resolved using pointers.

Comment: user3758232 Do you want all strings the same size?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by fixed-size.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest is:

```
char data[2][4] = {"abc", "def"};
```